# Cmake problem when using make with multiple threads

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake

I have a CMake project. When I run

```
make -j all
```

or

```
make -j 2
```

then I get errors such as

```
/usr/bin/cmake/usr/bin/cmake: : error while loading shared libraries: libasn1.so.8: error while loading shared librariescannot open shared object file: Operation not permitted
: libunistring.so.2: cannot open shared object file: Operation not permitted
src/sco/node/CMakeFiles/rtspreader.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/sco/node/CMakeFiles/rtspreader.dir/RtspReader.cpp.o' failed
```

or

```
    In file included from /home/sstoenescu/Work/legobox/src/sco/node/decision/NonScanScoreCalculator.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/iostream:39:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/ostream:38:10: fatal error: 'ios' file not found
```

However, when I simply run

```
make
```

without any threads, it works fine.

Every time I run make -j all I get different errors, but basically they are of these two types.

Do you know what might be wrong? The project is too large to post some code or some relevant CMakeLists.txt content. Please tell me if you need extra information, because I am not sure how to formulate this question.

Also, this happens with other projects as well, so I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my system, and not my projects.

Thanks!

Comment: Which CMake version and platform are you running on?

Comment: cmake 3.10.2, I am using clang-5.0 as compiler, platform is Ubuntu 18 (if that's what you're asking)

Comment: I'd try upgrading cmake to the latest and see what happens.  When you run `make` it will use `cmake` to perform some actions.  I would guess that if you run `make -j` then it could try to run multiple concurrent instances of `cmake`.  The first error seems that `cmake` can't run correctly because sometimes it can not open the shared libraries it needs to use.